# What is the difference between a fraction, ratio, quotient, rational number?

Tags: terminology, fractions, rational-numbers, ratio

They are mixed everywhere and I can't find a single article that treats them right and with the required rigor they should get. Can someone explain them?

Comment: Try some of the work of [Wu](https://math.berkeley.edu/~wu/NMPfractions.pdf).  He has thought a great deal about the best way to express many of the relations you are after.

Comment: Quotient can also mean partition by equivalence relation, in some sense quotient groups.